# Back button in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to implement a simple Lotka-Voltery simulation. I have a main QDialog Class in which I put three buttons to choose the options.

1. Button for simple simulation,
2. simulation with hideouts,
3. simulation with competition.

Each of these options are implemented in separated class.

When I click on each button I use connect function to close option window and show appropriate QDialog window (one of three options) and it works well.

I have problem with implementing back button. Analogously I can put an object of an option_window class, put in each windows and make a connection function like this:

```
connect ( back_button,SIGNAL(clicked()), Options_Window, SLOT(show()));
```

but it is not going to work because in my option_window class I already have objects of the rest of class.

It looks like the `class A` have an object of `class B` inside, and the `class B` have an object of `class A` inside. It won't work. What should I do ?

Here is a `Window_Option` header file.

```
namespace Ui {
    class Window_Option;
}

class Window_Option : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Window_Option(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Window_Option();
    MainWindow *simple;
    MainWindowHide *hideout;
    MainWindowComp *competition;

private:
    Ui::Window_Option *ui;
};
```

Comment: google forward declaration :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks like the class A have an object of class B inside, and the
>   class B have an object of class A inside. It won't work. What should I
>   do ?

Said like that, that is impossible. But if, instead, the class B contains a *pointer* to an object of class A, you can forward-declare the class A before the definition of class B.